# Adding a Dynamic Number of Blank Pages in Microsoft Word 2021

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, publishing

I'm wondering if there is a way to have MS Word dynamically add a number of blank pages right before the last page in a document.

I'm preparing manuscripts to send to a publisher. The publisher prints pages in multiples of 12, which means that if a book has, say, 200 pages, the publisher will print 4 blank pages at the end to bump it up to the next multiple of 12. This means the last page, the page with links on it, is buried and isn't the last page when printed. I don't want readers to miss this page and I figure it gets more visibility at the very last page when readers flip to the end rather than buried behind a few blank pages.

I'm wondering if there is a field in Word I can use to dynamically add the required number of pages so that it's a multiple of 12 and that link page appears right under the back cover. I know I can add the number of pages myself with page breaks, but I'm wondering if I can get Word to do the thinking for me, especially if I modify the manuscript and the number of pages changes.

Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the page number of the penultimate page then you may be able to do this as below. Notice that trying to use the page number of the *last* page (e.g. using a `{ NUMPAGES }` field) will probably cause problems because of course once your field codes insert new pages, the result of `{ NUMPAGES }` will go up. I have assumed that you can use the `{ PAGE }` field, but in a more complex document that may not be so simple. MY guess is that this will only work if your publisher is either using a desktop version of Word or a very faithful format conversion program.

You could then use field coding along the following lines. Where I have put `<pb>` you need to insert an actual page break. *All* the { } need to be the special field brace pairs that you can insert on Windows desktop Word using ctrl-F9.

```
{ SET PAGES { =12-MOD({PAGE},12) }{IF PAGES > 0 "<PB>" }{IF PAGES > 1 "<PB>" }{IF PAGES > 2 "<PB>" }{IF PAGES > 3 "<PB>" }{IF PAGES > 4 "<PB>" }{IF PAGES > 5 "<PB>" }{IF PAGES > 6 "<PB>" }{IF PAGES > 7 "<PB>" }{IF PAGES > 8 "<PB>" }{IF PAGES > 9 "<PB>" }{IF PAGES > 10 "<PB>" }
```

Comment: This probably needs a bit of tweaking to deal with the case where pages=12 but not time to deal with it right now.